# upgrading to Automatic Reference Counting and cleaning up my code

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.6

I have a project from 2 years ago that I'd like to bring back into action in xcode.

Is there a simple way to do away with the old style memory management I have in there with retain/releases and use the new .. ARM?

And this is a 32bit app using the QTKit and QuickTime frameworks - can this become a 64bit app that I can put on the App Store one day if it works well?

Also I realise that my app is one enormous .h and .m file - i'd like to break it into smaller files to make it easier to read and find what i am doing - any tips on how to do that?

Thanks guys!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Xcode menu item `Edit->Refactor->Convert To Objective-C ARC` which can automatically convert everything to ARC.

You can also use `Edit->Refactor->Convert to Modern Objective-C syntax` to update the code to use the new array/dictionary/number literal syntax.

For breaking out one file into many, Xcode's built-in refacting support is pretty terrible. You can try out [Jetbrains Appcode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) which has much better support for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your tips. I have noticed that going from 32 to 64bit (needed to implement ARC it seems) is not possible for me as I am referencing the QuickTime framework. Looks like I may need to get into AV foundation to be able to read video timecode and other goodies. Thanks for the link to Jetbrains Appcode - going to check it out